# AFTER INSERT Trigger to insert data into a different table after inserting it into initial table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, workbench

Hello and thanks in advance for any help given!

I have created a very simple database for an electronics online shop.

Among the other tables I have a tbl_orders for orders being placed manually (user inserts the product_id, number of units, payment_details_id and so on manually) and I want to make an AFTER INSERT trigger on tbl_orders that would send the order_id (which is tbl_order's PK) to a table called purchase_history.

The table purchase_history also has a purchase_date column. It's PK is purchase_id, with order_id as a FK.

I am unfamiliar with triggers but I've tried all sorts of simple queries inside a trigger with no luck, though the errors I was getting were getting "better" if one could call it that.

The last try I had was this:

```
  CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER      `onlineshop`.`tbl_orders_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_orders` FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

  INSERT INTO purchase_history (order_id)
  VALUES (NEW.order_id);

  INSERT INTO purchase_history ( purchase_date )

  VALUES (purchase_date = NOW());


  END
```

I am using MYSQL Workbench, which is great but also, sometimes, slightly buggy or confusing.

Comment: What was the error for the last try?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_orders_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_orders` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO purchase_history (order_id, purchase_date) VALUES (NEW.order_id, NOW());

END;
```

This way your insert would make more sense, as you would want both of the data in the same row in the history, I'd guess.

If the DEFINER-line is needed:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER stuff.`tbl_orders_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_orders` 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO purchase_history (order_id, purchase_date) VALUES (NEW.order_id, NOW());
```

I tried some things, mysql seems not to like `begin`, `end` and `DEFINER = ...` at the same time when creating triggers. Though `BEGIN` and `END` are not needed with triggers so there is no problem in removing them from your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below syntax to execute it. First we need to change delimiter if there is multiple statament.

```
DELIMITER #

create trigger SportsTriggerInsert after insert on sports 
  for each row begin 
     insert into settings(sports_id, auto_add_on_matches) 
     values (new.id, 0);
  end;#
DELIMITER ;
```